# Can/should model contain properties/variables only for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, model

What is common/best practice for data stored in model. I'm writing unit tests for calculations and i have a property that returns a value of other properties that are actually used for storing data in database. In model it is defined like this

```
    bool IsDebtAndPayCurrencyTheSame;

    public decimal leftOverDebtInSystemCurrencyForDate
    {
        get { return IsDebtAndPayCurrencyTheSame ? debt.allDebt.systemCurrency : Math.Round(debt.leftOverDebt.documentCurrency * Convert.ToDecimal(DebtCurrencyKoefPayoDate), 2); }
    }
```

and unit test looks something like this

```
        Assert.AreEqual(100, income.detailRow[0].account.leftOverDebtInSystemValueForDate);
```

So should i leave `leftOverDebtInSystemCurrencyForDate` in model or copy it's logic to unit test ?

Comment: How should we know? If the member clearly belongs to your model, than it should surely be implemented there. There is nothing specific to testing here, it´s all about class-design.

Comment: Creating a model just for unit test is never recommended, you should probably use the logic just

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can Model contain properties just for unit testing ?**

Well, there is no restriction.  You can add whatever properties you want.

**Should you do that ?**

NO.  It is not good practice to add such properties.  Again it's all about how you want to design your classes.  As per rules of abstraction and encapsulations, you should expose only required properties to the class consumers.

Ideally in unit testing also, you should check the end results of the class /method being tested rather than testing internal / private variables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If `leftOverDebtInSystemCurrencyForDate` is completely irrelevant to your application, it should be removed from your code.

If `leftOverDebtInSystemCurrencyForDate` is accessed by your application (other than unit-test), it should remain in your model or be extracted into a service.

Unit-test shouldn't contain any logic for `leftOverDebtInSystemCurrencyForDate`.